# Attempting to print a tree in C++ (Not using x's)

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to print a tree using C++. I can print the tree using only the "/"'s, but I need to use both "/" and "\"'s on each side of the tree, with empty space in between, if that makes sense. I need to make the "cone part of the tree" with only 3 "for" loops.

I'm good with the base and the trunk, but I need help with the cone.

I know that I need to account for the empty spaces on each side of the cone and inside each side of the cones but everything I try messes it all up, and being as new as I am I'm having a hard time keeping it at 3 "for" loops. Also, my teacher looks down at using the internet as a learning resource, so anything outside of "for" loops for this  program with throw red flags. Any help is appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    cout << "Please enter a height for the cone of the tree. [3 - 15]: ";
    int height;
    cin >> height;

if(height < 3 || height > 15)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Value entered is out of bounds." << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}

int level = 0;
int space = 0;
int slashes = 0;
int base = 0;
int wood = 0;
int trunk = 0;

for (int level = 0; level < height; level++) //First "Cone" For Loop
{   
    for (int space = height - level - 1; space > 0; space--)  //Second "cone" for loop
        cout << ' ';
    for (int slashes = 0; slashes < 2 * level + 1; slashes++)  //Third "cone" for loop
        cout << '/';
        cout << endl;
}
for (int base = 0; base < 2 * height; base++)
    cout << '-';
    cout << endl;
for (int trunk = 0; trunk < (height / 2); trunk++)
{
    for( int wood = 0; wood < height - 1; wood++)
        cout << ' ';
        cout << '|' << '|';
        cout << endl;
}




system ("pause");
return 0;
 }

 Actual:                    

     /                                     
    ///
   /////
  ///////
 /////////
///////////
------------
     ||
     ||
     ||
 Expected:
     /\
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
 /        \
/          \
------------
     ||
     ||
     ||
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else Googling this, here is how I did it. It's ugly and probably wrong, but it works.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a height for the cone of the tree. [3 - 15]: ";
    int height;
    cin >> height;

if(height < 3 || height > 15)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Value entered is out of bounds." << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}

int level = 0;
int space = 0;
int base = 0;
int trunk = 0;

for (int level = 0; level < height; level++)
{   
    for (int space = height - level - 1; space > 0; space--)
        cout << ' ';
        cout << '/';
    for (int space = 0; space < (2 * level); space++)
        cout << ' ';
        cout << '\\';
        cout << endl;
}
for (int base = 0; base < 2 * height; base++)
    cout << '-';
    cout << endl;
for (int trunk = 0; trunk < (height / 2); trunk++)
{
    for( int trunk = 0; trunk < height - 1; trunk++)
        cout << ' ';
        cout << '|' << '|';
        cout << endl;
}

//system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```